# Authorization with: dynamic groups, permission based content lists, micro-services based architecture?

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-security, authorization, spring-cloud

I'm not sure if Spring Security / Spring Cloud can be useful for my authorization needs.
This is my use-case:

- I've a CMS-like application.
- A content can be assigned to one or more 'groups'
- A content can be viewed by a user if this user belongs to at least  one of the groups.
- **Important note**: these groups are not hardcoded! Through the web application, the users can create (at run-time)  new custom defined groups, so the groups and the users are inside DB tables.

Example: a content is assigned to the groups: 'Germany', 'Sweden', 'Programmers', 'Managers'.

- a Manager from Germany can read that content
- a Manager from France can read that content (he is a at least a  Manager)
- a UX Designer from France cannot read that content.

In order to manage permission to access a single content, the check is quite simple!

My biggest issue is about **listing contents** that a user is allowed to see. Currently I manage this through SQL queries. I join the contents with their assigned groups, then I use this kind of SQL to filter the contents:

```
... WHERE ... group IN  [[list of groups associated to the authenticated user]]
```

In order to prevent performance issue, these query results are cached.

The problems seems worse when I add 'data' to these contents, let's imagine this contents can be commented. I want to list just the comment a user is authorized to see.

The rule is quite simple, you can read a comment if you are allowed to see its parent content.

Again, if I want to check the user permissions to see a single comment, the check is very simple, but things are more difficult if I want to list comments.

And... finally, if I want to adopt a microservice based architecture, the comments will be managed by a different service (no?). But in order to list the comments a user is allowed to see I'd need again all the "users & groups" information, so a micro-service based architecture doesn't seem so appropriate.

Am I totally wrong in my design approach?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need Spring Security combined with Access Control List (Spring Security ACL) that is the most fine grained user-permission based on domain object security permission.

With ACL you can assign permission to specific data (equivalent to a row in your database, to understand each other) like read or write and you can also assign to a user or a group.

Spring Security with ACL covers all the scenario you described and you can find an example to [start here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl)

> the comments will be managed by a different service (no?)

This is up to you, it depends on your scenario

> But in order to list the comments a user is allowed to see I'd need
>   again all the "users & groups" information,

Sure! When you filter information you need to know logged user with related groups/roles

> , so a micro-service based architecture doesn't seem so appropriate.

Why? You often need user information (and if you have user you can read related data if needed) and this happens in microservices too. You need to transfer user information between one microservice to another (ex. using JWT)